# Guzzle with telegram Bot API - 'GetMe' method not displaying a user object

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle, telegram-bot

I have the code

```
public function getClient(){
 $token = getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN');
 $uri = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/';
 $client = new Client(['base_url' => $uri]);
 return $client;
}

public function getMyBot(){
 $client = $this->getClient();
 $response = $client->get( '/getMe' );
 dd($response);
}
```

But instead of returning the user object like stated in the [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getme), I get shown a 'response' object instead.

```
Response {#188 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -effectiveUrl: "https://core.telegram.org/bots"
  -headers: array:9 [▼
    "server" => array:1 [▶]
    "date" => array:1 [▶]
    "content-type" => array:1 [▶]
    "content-length" => array:1 [▶]
    "connection" => array:1 [▶]
    "pragma" => array:1 [▶]
    "cache-control" => array:1 [▶]
    "x-frame-options" => array:1 [▶]
    "strict-transport-security" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:9 [▼
    "server" => "Server"
    "date" => "Date"
    "content-type" => "Content-Type"
    "content-length" => "Content-Length"
    "connection" => "Connection"
    "pragma" => "Pragma"
    "cache-control" => "Cache-control"
    "x-frame-options" => "X-Frame-Options"
    "strict-transport-security" => "Strict-Transport-Security"
  ]
  -body: Stream {#189 ▼
    -stream: :stream {@280 ▶}
    -size: null
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
  -protocolVersion: "1.1"
}
```

Anyway to obtain the user object? I am using php 5.4 with Guzzle 5.3, and laravel 5.0.

Edit: I tried using the getBody() method as well as getBody->getContents() method but it doesn't work, getBody will just show the streams part of the response, getContents will give a weird HTML file.

JSON_DECODE doesn't work as well, it returns error code 4 which is JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX. Is the response supposed to be a JSON form?

Comment: Read and parse the body, it should contain (in JSON format) the User object. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#using-responses

Comment: Using the getbody() method I will get a stream:
    Stream {#189 ▼
  -stream: :stream {@280 ▶}
  -size: null
  -seekable: true
  -readable: true
  -writable: true
  -uri: "php://temp"
  -customMetadata: []
}

Comment: Using body->getContents(); gets a html file containing 

      <title>Bots: An introduction for developers</title>
...
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need display the contant of body.

```
dd($response->getBody()->getContents())
```

By the way, you can use the [unofficial laravel reqady SDK](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk), which also works with Guzzle.

Comment: When I do that I get [a weird webpage: link to screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/ivlni0/9), unfortunately I can't use that SDK cuz it uses Guzzle 6 and PHP 5.5, but I'm hosting it on open shift with Guzzle 5 and PHP 5.4 :(

Comment: Check your token.
If you see example `https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11/getMe`
You will see token must contain ":"
If you make mistake in token you will have redirect to https://core.telegram.org/bots

Comment: +1 THANK YOU it was the token, my mistake was putting it in the .env file for local development but forgetting to put it on .openshift\.env as well. Hahahaha small beginnings~